# CKEditor: How to stop angle brackets from converting to HTML entities

Tags: ckeditor

Our site is using tags like <# TAGNAME #> but CKEditor converts < and > to &lt and &gt which breaks these tags for use in our software.

I've discovered this option: config.protectedSource.push( /<#[\s\S]*##>/g ); which seems to stop the conversion if the data is saved from Source mode, but in WYSIWYG mode I can't find a way to stop the conversion. I've tried many options in their API but none of them seem to have helped, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Were were looking at using CKEDitor to edit Smarty templates. The problem we were hitting was that it was replacing all the angle brackets and ampersands within the curly brackets, which messed everything up. This came up in a Google search so our solution should help anyone with similar issues.

CKEditor rebuilds the HTML every time you switch to Source mode and when you save, so you need to add to the HTML http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor  htmlFilter.

This worked for us:

```
//replace Form_content with whatever your editor's id is.
  htmlParser = CKEDITOR.instances.Form_content.dataProcessor.htmlFilter;

            //We don't want HTML encoding on smarty tags
            //so we need to change things in curly brackets
            htmlParser.onText = function(text) {
                    //find all bits in curly brackets                       
                    var matches = text.match(/\{([^}]+)\}/g);

                    //go through each match and replace the encoded characters
                    if (matches!=null) {
                        for (match in matches) {    

                            var replacedString=matches[match];
                            replacedString = matches[match].replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
                            replacedString = replacedString.replace(/&lt;/g,'<');
                            replacedString = replacedString.replace(/&amp;/g,'&'); 

                            text = text.replace(matches[match],replacedString);
                            }
                    }

                    return text;

            }
```

The onText function processes all the bits that aren't in tags or comments.

I'd imagine you can do something similar by altering the code above - I've left it as is as I think our problems and required solutions are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
editor.on( 'mode', function(ev) {
      if ( ev.editor.mode == 'source' ) {
                        var str=ev.editor.getData();
         str=str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&quot;/g, "\"");
         ev.editor.textarea.setValue(str);
      }
});
```

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20647&start=10

Answer (score 0):

If you type < or > in any WYSIWYG editor, they will be converted to their HTML entities in source mode.

Comment: I've stopped the HTML entities from converting in source mode, I want it so when the data is saved outside of source mode it won't convert the entities. We used to use EDITLET and it did not convert went posted in WYSIWYG mode.